# Constructing Basis Mirroring Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics

I have a $2^N$ dimensional basis of a vectorspace
$$
|s_1 \rangle \otimes |s_2 \rangle \otimes ... \otimes |s_N \rangle
$$
where $s_i \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow \}$ is the standard basis.
I need to construct $2^N \times 2^N$ a matrix $M$ that mirrors my kronecker product of basis vectors along the middle
$$
M |s_1 \rangle \otimes |s_2 \rangle \otimes ... \otimes |s_N \rangle
= |s_N \rangle \otimes |s_{N-1} \rangle \otimes ... \otimes |s_1 \rangle.
$$
I have calculated it for $N=1,2,3$ by hand
$$
M(N=1)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
M(N=2)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
M(N=3)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I would like to have a general formula for any $N$. It might be possible to construct it in terms of [commutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix). Also does this Matrix have a special name?